# Launching android application from the web

Tags: android, android-layout, android-emulator, android-widget, android-preferences

I have an application installed on Android emulator The code is below When I'm launching the emulator, I'm typing to the browser "market.android.com" and I want my application to be launched, but it doesn't start

Answer, please, the correct work of application could be provided by emulator or it's necessary to use the real device? (exactly to start application from android web browser)

```
<intent-filter>
  <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
  <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
  <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
  <data android:scheme="http" android:host="market.android.com"
        android:path="/search" />
</intent-filter>
```

Alternatively, there is the "intent:" scheme. This allows you to describe nearly any Intent as a URI, which the browser will try to launch when clicked. To build such a scheme, the best way is to just write the code to construct the Intent you want launched, and then print the result of intent.toUri(Intent.URI_INTENT_SCHEME).

You can use an action with this intent for to find any activity supporting that action. The browser will automatically add the BROWSABLE category to the intent before launching it, for security reasons; it also will strip any explicit component you have supplied for the same reason.

The best way to use this, if you want to ensure it launches only your app, is with your own scoped action and using Intent.setPackage() to say the Intent will only match your app package.

Trade-offs between the two:

http URIs require you have a domain you own. The user will always get the option to show the URI in the browser. It has very nice fall-back properties where if your app is not installed, they will simply land on your web site.

intent URIs require that your app already be installed and only on Android phones. The allow nearly any intent (but always have the BROWSABLE category included and not supporting explicit components). They allow you to direct the launch to only your app without the user having the option of instead going to the browser or any other app.

Thanks for any help (and code snippets)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> When I'm launching the emulator, I'm typing "market.android.com" and I want my application to be launched, but it doesn't start

It's not supposed to start in that scenario, assuming that by "typing" you mean "typing into the address bar". Browsers typically honor these sorts of `<intent-filter>` structures only for hyperlinks.

> Answer, please, the correct work of application could be provided by emulator or it's necessary to use the real device?

If you use a hyperlink, it should work on an emulator.

Comment: @user2331971: Have a Web page with a hyperlink in it.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that you are one step away from opening your app. Don't type the URL in browser, you need to have an URL somewhere else. Say, in SMS. You will have some kind of a text there and the link "http://market.android.com". When clicking on this link, you should see a dialog with an option to eather open it with a browser or with your app.

Sorry if I wrongly understood the question.

Comment: ...you're correct, but if I have a link (even in sms) I want to start my application from there

Comment: I don't see a problem here. You must see your app option in dialog. Just tap on it and your application will start.